# Adding an optional attachment to a asp.net c# form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with some code developed by a supplier.  Unfortunately the supplier is no longer available, so I'm trying to fix my problem myself!

This is my code:

```
    public ActionResult ReportaProblem(string title, string description, string url)
    {
        tblReportProblem feature = new tblReportProblem();
        var path = "";
        feature.Title = title;
        feature.Description = description;
        feature.DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        feature.UserId = AppConfig.LoginId;
        HttpPostedFileBase fu = Request.Files["fuScreenCapture"];
        if (fu.FileName != "")
        {
            string newName = "";
            var filename = "";
            filename = Path.GetFileName(fu.FileName).ToLower();
            newName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyHHmmss") + filename;
            path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Constants.Paths.ProblemImagePath + newName));
            fu.SaveAs(path);
            feature.FileName = newName;
        }
        if (_IProject.AddReportProblem(feature))
        {
            TempData["success"] = Constants.ReportProblemSuccess;
        }

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(path);
        ReportProblemEmailToAdmin(title, description, url, attachment);
        return RedirectToAction("ReportaProblem");
    }
```

Basically it allows a user to report a problem in the application. It includes the ability to add an attachment (i.e. a screen image).  The problem is that if the user doesn't attach a file, I get:

Server Error in '/' Application.
The parameter 'fileName' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: fileName

How do I allow the user to submit the problem report without an attachment?

Thanks, David.

Comment: What is the id of file upload control you have in your asp.net page?

Comment: I wasn't able to get ".HasFile" to work, but

Attachment attachment = null;
    if(path!= string.Empty) 
     {
       attachment = new Attachment(path);
     }

... worked great!  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the markup for upload control? Also, are you getting any error?

Comment: I have posted an alternate solution in my answer. You should try that since it seems you do not have asp file upload control in your markup but html file control.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I am very grateful!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `fileuploadcontrol` API in your C# code, and this control must be there in your aspx page. For example, you should have markup like below in your aspx page ( the id can be anything you want).

Since you have not provided any markup, so I have assumed that the id of file upload control is `fileUploadControl1`, and all code is based on this assumption.

**Markup for file upload control**

```
<asp:FileUpload id="fileUploadConrol1" runat="server" />
```

Then, your C# code should be like below.

1. Note that you need to first check if any file has been posted by
   checking the boolean flag `fileUploadConrol1.HasFile` and if true
   then you do your attachment logic else you skip the attachment
   logic.
2. Also, make sure that when `attachment` parameter is null in method
   `ReportProblemEmailToAdmin` then its appropriately handled.

**C# code using API of above file upload control**

```
public ActionResult ReportaProblem(string title, string description, string url)
{
    tblReportProblem feature = new tblReportProblem();
    var path = "";
    feature.Title = title;
    feature.Description = description;
    feature.DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    feature.UserId = AppConfig.LoginId;

    //fileUploadConrol1 is id of file upload control in your aspx markup
    if(fileUploadConrol1.HasFile)
    {
       //this line below is not needed
      //HttpPostedFileBase fu = Request.Files["fuScreenCapture"];
      //if (fu.FileName != "")
      //{
        string newName = "";
        var filename = "";
        filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUploadControl1.FileName).ToLower();
        newName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyHHmmss") + filename;
        path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Constants.Paths.ProblemImagePath + newName));
        fileUploadControl1.SaveAs(path);
        feature.FileName = newName;
      //}
    }
    if (_IProject.AddReportProblem(feature))
    {
        TempData["success"] = Constants.ReportProblemSuccess;
    }

    Attachment attachment = null;
    if(path!= string.Empty) 
     {
       attachment = new Attachment(path);
     }
    ReportProblemEmailToAdmin(title, description, url, attachment);
    return RedirectToAction("ReportaProblem");
}
```

**Alternate solution if you are using html file control and not asp fileupload control**

Use the C# code below, if you are using html file control rather than asp fileupload control. (NOTE: The above solution would work only if you have asp file upload file control. Use this alternate solution in your case).

```
public ActionResult ReportaProblem(string title, string description, string url)
{
tblReportProblem feature = new tblReportProblem();
var path = "";
feature.Title = title;
feature.Description = description;
feature.DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
feature.UserId = AppConfig.LoginId;

HttpPostedFile fu = null;

if (Request.Files.Count > 0 )
    {
       //get the posted file
       fu = Request.Files[0];

       //apply logic to posted file
       if(fu!=null) {
           string newName = "";
           var filename = "";
           filename = Path.GetFileName(fu.FileName).ToLower();
           newName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyHHmmss") + filename;
           path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Constants.Paths.ProblemImagePath + newName));
           fu.SaveAs(path);
           feature.FileName = newName;
       }
    }
if (_IProject.AddReportProblem(feature))
{
    TempData["success"] = Constants.ReportProblemSuccess;
}

Attachment attachment = null;
if(path!= string.Empty) 
 {
   attachment = new Attachment(path);
 }
ReportProblemEmailToAdmin(title, description, url, attachment);
return RedirectToAction("ReportaProblem");
}
```